# Confluent Kafka Golang Client Producer "Broker: Not enough in-sync replicas"

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am attempting to test out a producer writing messages to a topic on a kafka cluster using the Golang client. This works fine writing to a topic on a local cluster, I just copied and pasted the example code from their [github repo](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1/kafka"
)


func main() {

    p, err := kafka.NewProducer(&kafka.ConfigMap{"bootstrap.servers":"localhost"})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer p.Close()

    // Delivery report handler for produced messages
    go func() {
        for e := range p.Events() {
            switch ev := e.(type) {
            case *kafka.Message:
                if ev.TopicPartition.Error != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Delivery failed: %v\n", ev.TopicPartition)
                } else {
                    fmt.Printf("Delivered message to %v\n", ev.TopicPartition)
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    // Produce messages to topic (asynchronously)
    topic := "test"
    for _, word := range []string{"test message"} {
        p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
            TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
            Value:          []byte(word),
        }, nil)
    }

    // Wait for message deliveries before shutting down
    p.Flush(15 * 1000)
}
```

I receive the message on my console-consumer no issues.

I then try to do the same thing, just using my remote kafka cluster topic (note I also tried without the ports in the strings):

```
p, err := kafka.NewProducer(&kafka.ConfigMap{"bootstrap.servers":"HOSTNAME.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME2.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME3.amazonaws.com:9092"})
```

it prints the following error:

```
Delivery failed: test[0]@end(Broker: Not enough in-sync replicas)
```

The console producer has no issues though:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list HOSTNAME.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME2.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME3.amazonaws.com:9092 --topic test
>proving that this works
```

The console-consumer receives it:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server HOSTNAME.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME2.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME3.amazonaws.com:9092 --topic test --from-beginning 

proving that this works
```

Last thing I did was check to see how many In-Sync replicas there were for that topic. If I am reading this correctly, the min should be 2 and there are 3.

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server HOSTNAME1.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME2.amazonaws.com:9092,HOSTNAME3.amazonaws.com:9092 --topic test 
Topic:test      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:min.insync.replicas=2,flush.ms=10000,segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=86400000,flush.messages=9223372036854775807,max.message.bytes=1000012,min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5,unclean.leader.election.enable=true,retention.bytes=-1,delete.retention.ms=86400000,segment.ms=604800000
        Topic: test     Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 3     Isr: 3
```

Any ideas of what else I could look into?

Comment: Is the topic already created?  Sounds like you have an issue with your cluster.  If you have configured a minimum of 2 brokers for a new topic, you will not be able to produce to a new topic until there are 2 are available.

Comment: Yes the topic is already created. I wrote to it in the example from the console-producer. The console-consumer shows it was read. The golang code works to write to a topic on my local cluster, but not for the one on aws.

Comment: Working locally suggests that your code is ok. Have you tried AWS again after giving the cluster a few minutes to rebalance?

Comment: Also, having 2 replicas for 3 brokers is not recommended.  Check this article for more info https://hiya.com/blog/2018/06/07/hiyas-best-practices-around-kafka-consistency-and-availability/.  1 or 3 replicas may be better for your setup.

Comment: @PassKit I increased replication factor to 3 for my topic and it worked!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have `min.insync.replicas=2`, but the topic only has one replica.

If you have `request.required.acks=all` (which is the default), then the producer will fail because it cannot replicate what you've produced to the leader broker to the minimum set of required replicas

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md#topic-configuration-properties

I believe console producer only sets that property to just 1

> there are 3

There's actually only one. That's broker ID 3. You'd see a total of three separate numbers there as ISR if there were actually three replicas

Answer (score 2):

Or if you're using AWS's MSK, this could arise when the EBS storage per broker is completely used for one of the broker and the possible way to overcome is to increase it's storage.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30688379)